# App icon not visible in Sublime Text 6 after unzipping

Tags: finder, display, applications, icon, sublimetext

I just downloaded Sublime Text 6 from the official website and after the download completes immediately after unzipping, the app icon doesn't show up.

Please any remedy on how to address this will be so much appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted your Mac?